# Where can I find my Yahoo Developer API key(s)?

Tags: api, oauth, yahoo, api-key

I just registered for a yahoo developer API key. They did not e-mail me a link to it or information. It has been approved, but I can't figure out where to view the resulting API. All links with google seem to point to the application page, again.

Where the heck can I find my API key?!

ps: I hate you, Yahoo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

Visit the "My Projects Page" at https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects and click on the project you want the API key for.

Answer (score 0):

When you request the API itself it must be https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/wsregapp/
Yes, there is no link or shortcut visible there to view already approved API.
But I found this, just add ?view to view API you had.
just like this
https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/wsregapp/?view

Hope it helps